# Expected value given joint PDF

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two jointly continuous random variables with joint PDF

$$f_{XY}(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2} & x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad x-1<y<x\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Find $EY$.

What I tried:

$$EY = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f_{XY}(x, y) dy dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x-1}^{x} y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2} dy dx$$

but I don't know how to evaluate this integral.

Comment: As an aside, it is clear from the joint pdf that $$Y\mid X \sim U(X-1,X)$$ 

So, $$E\,[Y]=E\left[E\,[Y\mid X]\right]=E\left[\frac{X-1+X}{2}\right]$$

That is, $$E\,[Y]=E\,[X]-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x-1}^{x} y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2} dy dx &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12x^2} \frac{x^2-(x-1)^2}{2} \, dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12x^2} \frac{(2x-1)}{2} \, dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12x^2}\, dx - \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12x^2} \, dx
\end{align}

Using the property of normal pdf and definition of expectation, can you complete the rest?